# How many tasks can task scheduler run simultaneously

Tags: mysql, windows, backup, scheduled-tasks

How many tasks can task scheduler run at the same time?
I have set up three backup tasks from within SQLyog, all to start running at 12:00 am and run at subsequent 4 hours until midnight. Each task will backup all tables from three different databases to a network attached storage.

Will there be any impact on the MySQL Server performance or is there any chance for a task to be missed?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually considered proper to space out the scheduled tasks, even if only by 1 minute.
Since I don't know whether your tasks can be consolidated or optimized, and I don't know how long they'll take to run, I'll recommend you space them out by an hour or so.

There is some performance impact from a backup, which is part of the reason they're usually done at night (and, of course, there are fewer transactions being run on the database since people usually aren't working), and three running at the same time ... Well, it's not something I would wish on my database or my users.

To answer the original question: the scheduler can run a *lot* of things at the same time :)

Comment: That answer summed up everything! Thank you. I shall space them out accordingly. Each backup task runs for about 20 minutes or so. But we are actively looking for an incremental backup solution for MySQL that might keep the tasks light. Because backing up gigabytes of data once in 4 hours is really proving to be not that much resource and performance friendly.